# Is the ++ operator in System Verilog blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: system-verilog

Good coding convention says that we should use blocking assignments in a combinational block, and non-blocking assignments in a sequential block.  I want to use the `++` operator in a combinatorial block, but I don't know if it is blocking.  So is this code:

```
input [3:0] some_bus;
logic [2:0] count_ones;
always_comb begin
  count_ones = '0;
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
    if(some_bus[i])
      count_ones++;
  end
end
```

equivalent to this:

```
input [3:0] some_bus;
logic [2:0] count_ones;
always_comb begin
  count_ones = '0;
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
    if(some_bus[i])
      count_ones = count_ones + 1;
  end
end
```

or this:

```
input [3:0] some_bus;
logic [2:0] count_ones;
always_comb begin
  count_ones = '0;
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
    if(some_bus[i])
      count_ones <= count_ones + 1;
  end
end
```

I did look in the 1800-2012 standard but could not figure it out.  An answer that points me to the appropriate section in the standard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to section 11.4.2 of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), it is blocking.

> SystemVerilog includes the C increment and decrement assignment operators ++i , --i , i++ , and i-- . These do not need parentheses when used in expressions. These increment and decrement assignment operators behave as blocking assignments.

Comment: So is there a non-blocking equivalent to ++ or do we have to verbosely code:count_ones <= count_ones + 1;

Comment: @WestHamster I believe that is correct.  `val <= val+ 1;` will occur on the event.  At least, it is also well supported even if some standard does all an alternate in future.